# Cannot compile using ALSA

Tags: c, linker, alsa, portaudio

I am trying to create an C application on Debian GNU/Linux which uses the PortAudio interface. To do this I must compile my program with `gcc -lrt -lasound -ljack -lpthread -o YOUR_BINARY main.c libportaudio.a` from this [docs.](http://portaudio.com/docs/v19-doxydocs/compile_linux.html)

For this I installed `libasound2-dev`, and I checked where the files are using `apt-file search libasound.so`, this is the output:

```
lib32asound2: /usr/lib32/libasound.so.2
lib32asound2: /usr/lib32/libasound.so.2.0.0
lib32asound2-dev: /usr/lib32/libasound.so
libasound2: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libasound.so.2
libasound2: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libasound.so.2.0.0
libasound2-dev: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libasound.so
```

So the libasound should be installed correctly, but when I compile my program with this makefile:

```
DMXTest: main.c libdmx.a
    gcc -static -Wall main.c -L. -ldmx -lusb -lrt -lasound -ljack -lfftw3 -g -o main libportaudio.a
```

I get the following error: `/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lasound`.

How can I link this library correctly?

Comment: You have 32 and 64 bit libs, what's your system and gcc default?

Comment: My system default is 64 bit with mulitarch: `3.2.0-4-amd64`, and my gcc is: `gcc version 4.7.2 (Debian 4.7.2-5)` with `Target: x86_64-linux-gnu`.

Comment: You don't have `libasound.a` for `-static`... you cannot link a static binary.

Comment: But I just followed the instructions from the documentation from here http://portaudio.com/docs/v19-doxydocs/compile_linux.html, how should I do it then?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't have `libasound.a` for `-static`, you will need that, or you can almost certainly just remove `-static` from the `Makefile` (likely in `LDFLAGS` or `CFLAGS`).

There's is a related Debian bug [522544](http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=522544), and a related Ubuntu bug [#993959](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/alsa-lib/+bug/993959).

You may be able to build your own libasound from source, though as it also uses other libraries (notably `libpthread.so`, `librt.so` and `libdl.so`) I suspect it may remove some functionality when you build it statically, though it's supported with `./configure --enable-static` at build time
(or try `--enable-shared=no --enable-static=yes`).

FWIW, the use of static binaries is "[discouraged](http://www.akkadia.org/drepper/no_static_linking.html)" by the glibc maintainers, though I don't agree...

Comment: But I created my own static library, `libdmx.a`; how can I use that library then when I remove the `-static` line?

Comment: `-static` controls the end result, "dynamic" doesn't prevent use of `.a` files, they are really just libraries of `.o` files. So you *can* usually use `libdmx.a` in a dynamic executable (the opposite is not true, generally). Otherwise, can you recreate your library with with `-shared`?

Answer (score 3):

To compile my code i used the following command

```
gcc -o rec_mic rec_mic.c -lasound
```

and it works perfectly, without create my own static library.

Comment: Wacky but same here.  I have no asound.so but I do have libasound.so.